# Foldr code snippet

Tags: haskell

The function `traverse` takes an element and a map, and returns another element and a new (updated) map.

Given a list of elements `xs0` and an initial map `m0`, I need to apply `traverse` to each element of the list while passing in the updated map to each new invocation of `traverse`, to produce a list of resulting elements and the last returned map:

```
foldr (\x (xs, m) -> let (x', m') = traverse x m
                     in (x':xs, m')) ([], m0) xs0
```

Is there a way to reduce all this clutter and use prelude as much as possible?

Comment: Are you using the standard `traverse` from the `Traversable` class, or something else? If it's something else, what's its type? And for that matter, what's the type of the full expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much want `mapAccumR`, except that one has all of the argument orders and pair orders backwards, or the `State` monad, except that one passes its state to the right. We can define our own `mapAccumR`:

```
mapAccumR :: (a -> s -> (b, s)) -> [a] -> s -> ([b], s)
mapAccumR f as s = foldr (\a (bs, s') -> let (b, s'') = f a s' in (b:bs, s'')) ([], s) as
```

As you can see, foldr also has its argument order wrong.

Now your code is `mapAccumR traverse`, except that you had the argument order wrong at the end there. :)

This implementation of `mapAccumR` is almost identical to your code, but the average reader will have heard of `mapAccumR` and the average stackoverflow voter evidently finds its code confusing out of context.